# Measurement isolated loop with Op Amp

Tags: amplifier, operational-amplifier, vcm, isolated

I'm trying to measure a voltage across an Rsense (R2) in a galvanic isolated loop that flows a current (4 - 20mA).

My Op Amp has Vcm +20V. But I'm worried about the voltage in nodes B and A with respect to GNDA.

My intuition is that the galvanic isolation will be corrupted and GNDA and GNDB will have same potential.

What would be the voltage in these nodes with respect to GNDB if the isolation breaks?

I know that I could measure directly to R1 but I want a circuit that can be used to measure shunt resistors like in high current measurements

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Nt5F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you need to maintain isolation, you may want to look into isolation amplifiers. They're more expensive, but they can maintain galvanic isolation between the input and output.

Answer (score 1):

There's no galvanic isolation in your circuit, so if there is no external source driving the difference between the two grounds, it will settle out to  be a significant fraction of the voltage across R1.

Comment: There's no isolation because the inputs of op amp break it, right?

Comment: Yes, they tie the two grounds together.

Comment: What's the exact potential between of those grounds?

Comment: You can work it out, it will depend on values of R3/R4/R5/R6 (the gain).

Comment: what is the formula for that calculation? Is there any source to look at for further reading?